# How to update a dataframe column with a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a Dataframe with values already in it.
I have computed a numpy array and using the for loop , i need to

1. Insert a new column into the dataframe (only for the first time)
2. Append the computed numpy to the new column as a dataframe

This is the basic code for now
b = It is a list of unique dataframe values

```
for i in b:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        //numpyarray=compute the numpy array
        dataframe["newcolumn"] = numpyarray
```

But now only the last loop values are in the new column .
I am not able to update it.

Edit: The dataframe to which the new column to be added is grouped into 3 unique values which is in "b"
I am trying to rank these dataframe values and then insert the new column "Rank" to the dataframe.
But the rank is being added to the last set of loop only.

#here is the full code

```
b=[]
a=df['Priority'].unique()
b.append(a)
df2=df.groupby('Priority')
for i in b:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        df3=df2.get_group(i[j])
      
    matrix=df3[['Aging','DisputePercent','TotalAmount']].to_numpy()
        weights = np.array([0.25, 0.3,0.45])
        types = np.array([-1, 1, 1])
        vikor = VIKOR()
        pref = vikor(matrix, weights, types)
        rank = rank_preferences(pref, reverse = False)

        print('Preference values: ', np.round(pref, 4))
#         print('Ranking: ', rank)
        df3["Rank"] =rank
        df3.sort_values(by='Rank', ascending =True)
```

Comment: Don't use a loop, use numpy broadcasting but please provide some input data.

Comment: I have added the full code and the input data